# What will happen if I change the type of a column from int to year?

Tags: mysql, database, types

I have a table in MySQL 4.0 which currently has a year field as a smallint(6) type.  What will happen if I convert it directly to a Year type with a query like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY y YEAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

When the current members of column y have values like 2010?  I assume that because the year type is technically values from 1-255, values above that will be truncated or broken.

So if MySQL isn't smart enough to realize that 2010(int) = 110(year), what would be the simplest query or queries to convert the values?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's an interesting question. Have you *tried*? ;-) Should not be too hard to find out, IMHO.

Comment: Very true, but I don't have a test environment at work, so I was going to try when I got home.  If someone else already knows, all the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MySQL Docs: 10.3.3 The `year` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html)

> For four-digit format, MySQL displays YEAR values in YYYY format, with a range of 1901 to 2155, or 0000. For two-digit format, MySQL displays only the last two (least significant) digits; for example, 70 (1970 or 2070) or 69 (2069).

For years out of that range:

> Illegal YEAR values are converted to 0000.

---

#### A quick test

```
alter table foo add b year(4) not null default current_timestamp;
update foo set b=a;

a       b
1900    0000
1901    1901
1950    1950
2000    2000
2002    2002
2121    2121
2155    2155
2156    0000
```